# How Join works in SQL?

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance

If I have three tables say A,B and C

A is join to B and
B is join to C

Then is it required to join A to C?

I tried this with join A to C and because of this my query performance is increased but I dont understand how my query performance increased?

It will be very helpful if you can explain me why A to C join increase the performance?

there are 3 tables. 
`AWARD_MEMBER`, `HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER` and `CONDITIONALITY_GROUP` 
This is how i joined them,

```
AWARD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID = HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID AND 
HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID = CONDITIONALITY_GROUP.HH_MEMBER_ID AND
AWARD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID = CONDITIONALITY_GROUP.HH_MEMBER_ID
```

say `AWARD_MEMBER as A,` `HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER as B` and `CONDITIONALITY_GROUP as C`
so `AWARD_MEMBER.HH_MEMBER_ID = CONDITIONALITY_GROUP.HH_MEMBER_ID` join is really required in query? If yes then how it works?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question without seeing the queries and the definitions of your tables. Such things as indexes, `ON` clauses , and lists of columns being retrieved have a large consequence to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not mentioning about the table structure i cant say why it is happening (increasing perfomance while joining A to C ).

But if you are looking for  performance optimisation , you should look at the `EXPALIN` keyword.

`EXPLAIN` is one of the most powerful tools at your disposal for understanding and optimizing troublesome MySQL queries

- **EXPALIN**

  `EXPALIN` returns  a row of information for each table used in the `SELECT` statement.These are the output columns produced by `EXPLAIN`.
  [image]

> The `type` column of EXPLAIN output describes how tables are joined.
>
> The following list describes the join types, ordered from the best
>   type to the worst
>
> - system
> - const
> - eq_ref
> - ref
> - fulltext
> - ref_or_null
> - index_merge
> - unique_subquery
> - index_subquery
> - range
> - index
> - ALL

---

> The "`rows`" column in the `EXPLAIN` output is an estimate of the number
>   of rows that need to be examined.
>
> Whether or not the query will actually need to examine every row in
>   the table really depends on the access plan (shown in other columns in
>   the EXPLAIN output. For example, an index range scan operation doesn't
>   have to look at EVERY row, only the rows in particular index range.
>   But a full scan operation will look at EVERY row in the table).

---

> By looking at `rows` and `type` you can easily understand why it got
>   improved when you joined (A to C).

Note : `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` - show you additional information about the way it executes the query.

Hope this helps..